# Updating large amounts of data in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a rails app with a table of about 30 million rows that I build from a text document my data provider gives me quarterly. From there I do some manipulation and comparison with some other tables and create an additional table with a more customized data.

My first time doing this, I ran a ruby script through Rails console. This was slow and obviously not the best way.

What is the best way to streamline this process and update it on my production server without any, or at least very limited downtime?

This is the process I'm thinking is best for now:

1. create rake tasks for reading in the data. Use activerecord-import plugin to do batch writing and to turn off activerecord validations. Load this data into brand new, duplicate tables.
2. Build indexes on newly created tables.
3. Rename newly created tables to the names the rails app is looking for.
4. Delete the old.

All of this I'm planning on doing right on the production server.

Is there a better way to do this?

Other notes from comments:

- Tables already exist
- Old tables and data are disposable
- Tables can be locked for select only
- Must minimize downtime
- Our current server situation is 2 High CPU Amazon EC2 instances. I believe they have 1.7GB of RAM so storing the entire import temporarily is probably not an option.
- New data is raw text file, line delimited. I have the script for parsing it already written in Ruby.

Comment: run the imports as background tasks with resque or delayed-job might work, are you in a hurry to get them in or just dont want your server slowing down when you run this.

Comment: A bit of a hurry. I'm more concerned with coming up with the most painless and automated process for doing this, as I'll have to do it every 3 months from now til' forever.

Comment: Possible routes depend on your precise requirements.
Does the table you need already exist? Does the structure ever change? Do you need the old data in the table? Doese the new data completely replace the old contents of the table(s)? Can you lock the table exclusively? Do you need to minimize downtime? Do you have enough RAM available to hold the entire imported data temporarily?

Comment: And last but not least: in what format do you get the new data? CSV?

Comment: See edits for answers to your Questions, Erwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create "my_table_new" as an empty clone of "my_table"
2) import the file (in batches of x lines) into my_new_table - indexes built as you go.
3) Run: RENAME TABLE my_table TO my_table_old, my_table_new TO my_table;

Doing this as one command makes it instant (close enough) so virtually no downtime. I've done this with large data sets, and as its the rename that's the 'switch' you should retain uptime.

Comment: If you have any table / row locks goig on it will fail, we turned off all our workers while this ran then kicked them back on. If the server is doing lock then just find a time when it's not busy and execute till it Passes

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your logic, I would seriously consider processing the data in the database using SQL.  This is close to the data and 30m rows is typically not a thing you want to be pulling out of the database and comparing to other data you have also pulled out of the database.

So think outside of the Ruby on Rails box.

SQL has built-in capability to join data and compare data and insert and update tables, those capabilities can be very powerful and fast, allowing the data to be processed close to the data.